# Changing Horizontal Scrolling in Emacs

Tags: emacs, horizontal-scrolling, smooth-scrolling

Before using Emacs, I used Nano, and I would like to change the horizontal scrolling in Emacs to be slightly more intuitive.  Just for clarification, by horizontal scrolling, I mean the forward-char and backward-char movement out of the window boundaries, and not the <kbd>Ctrl+x ></kbd> commands.

The main thing I would like to figure out is how to have it only scroll one letter at a time (I guess like horizontal "smooth-scrolling"), or maybe even one full pane width at a time.

I've tried changing some variables containing "hscroll" (like hscroll-margin), but none of them seem to get me closer to the behavior I am looking for.

What variables should I be looking at to get horizontal scrolling working how I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you can get what you want with:

```
(setq hscroll-margin 0)
(setq hscroll-step 1)
```

If not, can you describe how you would like the behaviour to be.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.  I guess I didn't see "hscroll-step".  Thanks!

Comment: Also, and this may be better as a separate question, it looks like the margin behaves differently on the right side than it does the left.  Is there an easy way to make them both equal?